# Katalon Posibble to assert response = data?

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, assertion, katalon-studio, data-driven-tests

I store json test data in excel file.
Make use of apache POI to read the json data and parse it as request body, call it from katalon.

Then I write many lines of assertion (groovy assert) to verify each line response = test data.

Example:
Assert test.responseText.fieldA == 'abc'
Assert test.responseText.fieldB == 'xyz'
And so on if I have total of 20 fields.

I'm thinking of there is better way to make use of the json data stored in data file.
To assert the response = test data. So I can save alot of time to key in each line and modify them is the test data changed.

Please advise if this can be achieved?

Comment: You can use a for loop to loop through the excel file. Why do you store json data to excel file? Can you post example of your code?

Comment: We have quite a huge amount of data for a service. Sorting them in one file ease for modification if any key or value changed. Could you share the logic of for loop? I cannot let the loop to search freely in excel file.

Comment: Please check provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: you have two excel sheets - current values and expected values (values you are testing against).

Current values:

```
No. | key | value
----+-----+------
1     a     100
2     b     6
3     c     13
```

Expected values:

```
No. | key | value
----+-----+------
1     a     100
2     b     6
3     c     14
```

You need to add those to Data Files:

[image]

The following code will compare the values in the for loop and the assertion will fail on the third run (13!=14):

```
def expectedData = findTestData("expected")
def currentData = findTestData("current")

for(i=1; i<=currentData.getRowNumbers(); i++){
    assert currentData.getValue(2, i) == expectedData.getValue(2, i)
}
```

Failure message should look like this:

```
2020-07-02 15:16:40.471 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/table comparison FAILED.
Reason:
Assertion failed: 

assert currentData.getValue(2, i) == expectedData.getValue(2, i)
       |           |           |  |  |            |           |
       |           14          3  |  |            13          3
       |                          |  com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.reader.SheetPOI@5aabbb29
       |                          false
       com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.reader.SheetPOI@72c927f1
```

Comment: Great idea. I would say the expected value is fixed and defined by me, preloaded before test execution. current value should be the api response, value got after test execution. Questiob: I need to find a way to store them in the data filedynamically. Is katalon Data Files supporting this? Test case 01, executed, insert to data files, row 1....then compare. Test case 02, store result to data files row 2....and so on.

Comment: I don't think Data Files allow you to write to them natively. But there is certainly a way to do that using Groovy.

Comment: Alright then I have to think about it. Using my current POI method, but write to file. Then read them back.